# Operator with different spacing for binary operations

Tags: spacing, macros

I want to create a macro

```
\d
```

where something like

```
$4+\d x$
```

is interpreted as

```
$4+d\! x$
```

but

```
$\int f(x) \d x$
```

is interpreted as

```
$\int f(x) \,d\! x$
```

In essence, I want the macro to behave differently if it is preceded by a binary operation.

Comment: Are you *really* sure you want `d\!x`?

Comment: The standard `\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}` does what you want. Don't redefine `\d`.

Comment: So the \mathop takes care of the \, before the differential?

Comment: Yes, with `\mathop` you get the same behavior as with `\sin` or `\log`, that leave a thin space if preceded by an ordinary or closing symbol, but not with a binary operation or relation symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to define

```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}

$4+dx$ % for comparison

$4+\diff x$

\bigskip

$\displaystyle\int f(x) dx$ % for comparison

$\displaystyle\int f(x)\diff x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the output of `d\!x` is

[image]

which is clearly wrong.

### Note

Don't redefine `\d`, which is a command for accents. You'd regret doing it, sooner or later, for instance when you cite some Indian author.